# Proper design for a WCF service that accesses data

Tags: c#, database, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am designing a WCF service that accesses some data stored in a database.

The actual access to the DB is handled by some ORM layer (currently *NHibernate*, but this is an implementation detail).

I am wondering what is the proper design for this sort of scenario?

The naive approach would be something like:

```
public class ServiceImplementation : IService
{
     // NHibernate session
     private ISession session;

     // service methods that use *session*
}
```

This is coupled specifically to NHibernate and forces the service class to manage initialization and owning the ORM logic code.

My questions are in particular:

- How do i achieve a decoupled design where the service is decoupled from the DB/ORM layer?
- **When** and **who** should initialize the db access/ORM layer? does the service manage that?

Since this is such a common scenario, i assume some "patterns" / best practices exist.

Most examples that are available online, demonstrate HOW to achieve this (how to use an ORM to access a DB, etc) but not how this should be properly done from a design perspective, on a larger scale.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to initialize only once, you might want to consider setting up your service implementation class with the following attribute:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

This will cause your service to hold a single instance in memory, with multiple callers all accessing that instance.  The downside is that your code will have to be thread-safe; additionally, you won't be able to call through to a second WCF service (for this, you need Reentrant concurrency).

However, in this scenario, you can hold a class instance in your service which controls the DB/ORM side of things, achieving the decoupling you desire.

Initialization of the DB/ORM can be carried out in the service's constructor.

Note that it is not wise to make use of a static member variable containing DB/ORM functionality.  This is because even static values may be reclaimed by the service host given a sufficient period of inactivity.

This is of course only one way to achieve what you want: you might benefit from examining the cost of multiple initialization vs. the P.I.A. of writing thread-safe code.  A compromise would be to use InstanceContextMode.PerSession - a single user session would then have the ORM initialized only once, cutting down on initializations if a user is likely to make multiple calls.  The overhead of defining and controlling sessions is a minor irritant at best, and one which, given how long I've rambled on already, is outside the scope of this response.

Comment: I have already set ContextMode to single (not certain whether it's the most ideal choice). How does keeping a class instance of NHibernate on my service achieve a decoupled design?

Comment: If you create a class and put all the ORM initialization code into it, and just query it as needed, that would achieve decoupling.